# EXEC sp_executesql a parameter is not passed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need your help please, 
I read the forum but I'm still having a persistant problem without solution. I want to pass a variable into parameters of an SP_EXECUTESQL, but the result value of the passed variable is always ZERO in my SQL statement.

Here is my code :

```
declare @counter int
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

// ------ My @COUNTER value I want to get, it's ok

SET @counter = (
        select COUNT(CREATED_DT)
        from USERS
        where CAST(CREATED_DT as date) = CAST(@DATE_TIME as date)
)

// ------ I try to pass my @COUNTER value for my COUNTER_COLUMN, and it's not ok anymore...

SET @sql = N'update DATA_REPORT set COUNTER_COLUMN = @counterB';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@counterB int', @counterB = @counter;
```

I do not have errors on execution but in my SQL there is always :
COUNTER_COLUMN = 0 !!! 
I checked before that my @counter was not returning 0, and it returns perfectly miscenaneous good values.

Any clues about this issue ?
Thank you very much :)
Robin

Comment: your code looks ok to me, if you are getting a non 0 value from your select query, your executesql should work. By the way,why do you need dynamic sql ? there is nothing dynamic about your sql.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm thinking as you @ughai but it doesn't work. If I put '@ counterB' = 999 the value will be passed properly, and if I test '@ counter' the value return by the SELECT statement is good too :/ PS. for your question, yes you are right, I removed the dynamic part from my UPDATE statement in order to focus on the issue.

Comment: I'm no expert with permissions and all that fun stuff, but have you tried running your update script OUTSIDE the sp_executesql to see if the data change even works.

Comment: @Stephan, I'm using a TSQL software without that. It makes things harder. I could ask for the version.

Comment: Well "SELECT @@Version " gives you your version in SSMS, but I'm more interested in what your using. What is this is "TSQL Software" you mentioned?

Comment: Why the dynamic sql? It is adding a layer of complexity that isn't needed from what you posted. You should be able to do this thing in a single query with no variables at all.

Comment: Tip: `where CAST(CREATED_DT as date) = CAST(@DATE_TIME as date)` is not [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). You may not care at the moment, but it's worth learning about.

Comment: Add a `PRINT @counterB;` before you call `sp_ExecuteSql`.  It's probably passing in a zero because the `SELECT Count..` that is supposed to set it isn't returning any rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = N'update myTable set avg =   (
                                        select COUNT(CREATED_DT)
                                        from USERS
                                        where CAST(CREATED_DT as date) = CAST(@DATE_TIME as date)
                                        )';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Greatly simplifying this to remove the unnecessary dynamic sql it would like something like this.

```
update DATA_REPORT 
set COUNTER_COLUMN = 
(
    select COUNT(CREATED_DT)
    from USERS
    where CAST(CREATED_DT as date) = CAST(@DATE_TIME as date)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your query, i try to use 'concat' the parameter instead of using @counterB and it work just fine.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @counter int = 1
set @sql = concat(N'update DATA_REPORT set COUNTER_COLUMN = ', @counter);
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

@sql look like this

```
update DATA_REPORT set COUNTER_COLUMN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you,

Your answers were very interesting and helped me to think differently and to solve my issue. I choosed to execute my statement the more simple as possible without @parameters with sp_executesql. It made problems with the TYPE of my variables.

PS. @Rawitas Krungkaew > I didn't try CONCAT but keep it in mind, thk you.

```
   declare @dyn_col_account varchar(40);
   declare @DATE_TIME nvarchar(50)

   SET @counter = (
            select COUNT(CREATED_DT)
            from USERS
            where CAST(CREATED_DT as date) = CAST(@DATE_TIME as date)
    )
    DECLARE @query1 nvarchar(max) = '
            UPDATE DATA_REPORT 
            SET ['+@dyn_col_account+'] = '+ @counter +' 
            WHERE TIME_DAY=cast('''+@DATE_TIME+''' as date)' 

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query1
```